# «Дорівнює» і «рівний»

Tags: вибір-слова

Чому в математичних виразах ми кажемо, наприклад, *менший або дорівнює*, а не *менший або рівний*?

Чи це тому, що російською є *ровньій* і *равньій*, а українською тільки *рівний* чи просто тому що так повелось вже? Адже в [словниковій статті](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&highlight=on) я бачу:

> **equal** = ['i:kwəl] рі́вний; одна́ко́вий

Особисто мені коротший варіант більше подобається, але не певен чи можна його вживати.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не впевнений, чи це строга відповідь за канонами української мови, бо я все ж таки математик.

Щиро кажучи, вживаю ще лаконічніший вираз „менше, рівне“ або „більше, рівне“, тобто пропускаю сполучник „або“. І ніколи цим не переймаюся.

Відповідь на ваше питання мабуть полягає у тому, що в українській мові є прикметник „рівний“ та відповідне йому дієслово „дорівнювати“. Натомість також існує ступінь порівняння „менший“ від прикметника „малий“, але відповідного йому дієслова не існує. Бо „зменшити“, „применшити“ означають дію, яку слід зробити, і не позначають поточного стану. Водночас таке слово „доменшити“ не знайшло широкого використання у математичній термінології. Та й узагалі я не знайшов його в жодному словнику. 
А із прикметника „малий“ складно утворити дієслово для позначення відповідної дії. 
Щоправда, на [e2u.org.ua](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&dicts=all&highlight=on) знайшов дієслова „мали́ти та мали́тися“. Відповідно вираз „5 ≤ 7“ можна було б читати як „п'ять малиться, дорівнює сім“. Але це суто умоглядно.

Comment: Мабуть, все-таки «менше-рівне», а не «менше, рівне». Тобто я думаю, це просто словесне озвучення знаку «≤», одна лексична одиниця — а не дві окремі одиниці (інакше їх би радше інтерпретували як «менше *та* рівне», а не «менше *чи* рівне» — що було б нісенітницею з математичної точки зору; а «менше-рівне» — як нове, можливо розмовне, слово на позначення «≤»). Чи я неправий?

Comment: «[Малі́ти](http://sum.in.ua/s/mality)» (і припускаю, що «малити» та «малитися» також) означає «меншати», «зменшуватися», «*ставати* меншим». Тобто, на мою думку, воно так само семантично не відповідає дієслову «дорівнювати» (що означає «вважати рівним», «*бути* рівним» — а не «ставати рівним»), як і «зменшити». Недостатньо знайти дієслово, треба ще щоб воно було семантично влучним; наприклад, «височіти» означає саме «бути високим», це майже потрібне значення («сім височіє над п'ятьма», «*b* височіє над чи дорівнює *q*»), але от антоніма не бачу.

Comment: Згідний з вашим зауваженням про „менше-рівне“. З огляду на ваше „височіє…“ мені спало на думку „маліє…“ Відповідний текст мав би виглядати так „b маліє перед чи дорівнює q“.

Comment: Ну просто в словнику «маліє» — «меншає», «стає меншим» (а не «є малим», «виділяється малим розміром»). А «височіє» — «є високим», «виділяється висотою» (а не «стає вище»). Хоча припускаю, що в «маліти» можуть бути значення поза словником.

Comment: Андрію, як я зрозумів ви займаєтесь математикою? Може вам було б цікаво взяти участь в проекті з перекладу університетського підручнику з алгоритмів. Робота оплачувана, але не на дійсно достойному рівні. Але вона має інші переваги. Можливо це було б цікаво вашим знайомим. Зі мною можна зв'язатись через Skype - igor.yalovetskyy, або написати сюди https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0:Igor_Yalovecky