# "Збігатись" замість "співпадати"

Tags: вибір-слова

Чи правильно завжди використовувати *збігатись* замість *співпадати*? Збіжність вже має своє математичне значення як [збіжність ряду](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4). Чи краще казати, що значення *співпадають* чи *збігаються*? А як щодо думок, вони *збігаються* чи *співпадають*?

Comment: Мені важко судити, наскільки «співпадати» є правильним чи неправильним (з одного боку — явний росіянізм, з іншого — широковживане). Але в тих випадках, коли при «збігаються»/«сходяться» виникає неоднозначність із терміном для рядів, можна скористатись чимось на кшталт «виявилися однаковими/рівними».

Comment: Також дієслово «сходитися» в українській мові, здається, не є математичним терміном — відповідно вираз, наприклад, «значення зійшлися» формально не має конотації про [математичну границю](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Границя). Хоча з іншого боку, для тих, хто вивчав математику російською (російське _[сходимость](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сходимость)_), або просто через буквальне розуміння дієслова «сходитися», така конотація все одно може виникнути. Однак в певних випадках все-таки можна використати і «сходитися».

Comment: Цікаво, чи стосується якось цього питання слово `збіговисько`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ось, що про це пише [Українській простір](http://prostir.co.ua/zbihajetsya-chy-spivpadaje-7047/):

> Як зазначають у своїх працях Борис Антоненко-Давидович, Олександр
>   Пономарів та Іван Вихованець, **словотворча модель української мови
>   зберігає префікс “спів-” переважно у словах, які означають назви осіб,
>   що спільно з кимось роблять якусь справу**. Тобто форми співавтор,
>   співробітник, співучасник – літературно унормовані і виправдані.
>
> Питомими вважаються і слова “співчувати”, “співпрацювати”. Але це не
>   стосується таких відверто змавпованих слів, як “співпадати” чи
>   “співставляти”.
>
> Отож, у разі сумніву, яке слово вжити – “співпадати” чи “збігатися”,
>   вибір має бути на користь другого, як притаманного українській мові.

А значення можуть *дорівнювати*.

Див. також: [«Дорівнює» і «рівний»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1481).